# How to compute normals of mesh?

Tags: c++, graphics, directx

How do you find normals of mesh in c++ directx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `D3DXComputeNormals` function.

Comment: I declaration on MSDN.  I didn't get how am I gonna get normals after calling function?

Comment: They will be stored in vertices' data of your mesh, provided your vertex format can accomodate such data.